# Is there a way to find rank of a number (fraction) in an array like "CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(1,4,1,1),A,D,C,B)"?

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, ranking

I am trying to get the rank of a number from an array in the same cell.

something like this;

```
=RANK.EQ(A,CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},A,D,C,B),0)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with current formula? What do you want? Can you show some samples?

Comment: The *ref* parameter in `RANK.EQ` must be a reference to an actual worksheet range, or else some construction which resolves as such. `CHOOSE` returns an array, not a worksheet range.

Comment: Post some example data together with expected result.

Comment: You could try something like `=1+SUM(N(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},A,D,C,B)>A))`, though would need to see some examples to be sure.